# JavaScript method that returns the VARIABLE NAME of a TYPE BOOLEAN instead of the VALUE itself inside Template Literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

is there a function in "javascript" where I can make my variables(not the value) as strings like parseVariableName something?

for example, in my scenario I want to have a **dynamic classname using boolean variables **without creating an object, making it as array and looping**. i want to return the variable name it self not the value of the variable. with that, i can use it inside template literals

```
const { isPivotable = true, isTable, isGrid } = props

const cn =  `myClass--sample ${isPivotable || isTable || isGrid}`

//or

const isPivotable = true, 
const isTable = false
const isGrid = false

const cn =  `myClass--sample ${isPivotable || isTable || isGrid}`

//value true is converted as STRING
actual result: *myClass--sample true* 

//the variable isPivotTable "name" converted as string
expected result: *myClass--sample isPivotable*
```

example of the expected result but uses objects, and arrays in which **I want to avoid**.

```
const parseVariableName = (obj) => Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val])=> !acc && val ? key : acc, '')

isPivotable = false
isGrid = false
isDraggableTable = true

const answer = `class-sample--${parseVariableName({ isPivotable, isGrid, isDraggableTable})}`
console.log(answer)
```

why i ask this question because i want to make a variable name base on the variable i declared and i don't want to make my code longer just because of it.

i know it's stupid question to ask but i just want to share my thoughts.

Comment: Please [edit your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67679044/edit) instead of reposting it.

Comment: it was mark as closed and already answered but it's not the answer i'm looking for.

Comment: Then please edit it by adding an explanation how those answers didn't solve your problem. Notice the duplicate explains how what you're trying to do is impossible, you will have to live with some workaround.